# Why can XMLHttpRequest instance send only one request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, request

I'm trying to send a several requests from a single instance of `XMLHttpRequest` object, like this:

```
GC3D.Application.prototype.setMapTiles = function() {
    var ajaxInstance = new GC3D.Ajax();
    for ( var i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        var urlFinal = this.prepareRequestForTileDownload( i, j );
        ajaxInstance.sendRequest({
            id: { i: i, j: j },
            HttpMethod: 'GET',
            UrlEndpoint: urlFinal
        }).then( function( item ) {
                   //...
                });
       }

};
```

It doesn't work and sends only the one request. BUT! If to change source code to the next:

```
for ( var i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    var ajaxInstance = new GC3D.Ajax();
...
```

It begins to send so many requests as the total number of `for` loop iterations and all is working perfectly. I prefer to get known some features. As in C# development in my past I never create a new instance of some TCP socket in loop, if I want to make it asynchronously - I create a single instance with delegates to async functions and if there is a similar situation in C# project like in JavaScript code here in the question's content, because it's doesn't produce new objects in for loop, it takes less memory and as for architecture it's represented as more clean and good solution.

`GC3D.Ajax` is defined as the next prototype:

```
GC3D.Ajax = function() {
    this.httpRequest = undefined;
    this.listExceptions = undefined;
    this.init();
};
GC3D.Ajax.prototype.init = function() {
    this.listExceptions = [];

    if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) this.httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if ( window.ActiveXObject ) {
        try {
            this.httpRequest = new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' );
        }
        catch ( exception ) {
            this.listExceptions.push( exception );

            try {
                this.httpRequest = new ActiveXObject( 'Msxml2.XMLHTTP' );
            } 
            catch ( exception ) {
                this.listExceptions.push( exception );

                try {
                    this.httpRequest = new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' );
                } 
                catch ( exception ) {
                    this.listExceptions.push( exception );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ( !this.httpRequest ) {
        console.error( 'Can\'t create a HTTP Request instance for AJAX! Possible problems:' );
        console.error( this.listExceptions );
    }
};
GC3D.Ajax.prototype.sendRequest = function( properties ) {
    var defer = new GC3D.Defer();
    if ( this.httpRequest !== undefined ) {
        this.httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if ( this.httpRequest.readyState === 4 && this.httpRequest.status === 200 ) {
                var objectOutput = {};
                objectOutput.id = properties.id;
                objectOutput.content = this.httpRequest.responseText;
                defer.resolve( objectOutput );
            }
            else {
                var message = 'There was a problem with the request in GC3D.Ajax.';
                defer.reject( message );
            }
        }.bind( this );
        this.httpRequest.open( properties.HttpMethod, properties.UrlEndpoint );
        this.httpRequest.send();
    }
    else console.error( 'HTTP Request instance isn\'t defined!' );
    return defer.promise;
};
GC3D.Ajax.prototype.get = function() {
    return this.httpRequest;
};
```

Comment: because that's the API.

Answer (score 0):

The XMLHttpRequest API is very well defined and leaves no doubt about this behaviour.

The definition of the `open()` method, step 13, states that the method should:

```
Terminate the request.
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open()-method

Opening a debugger in the browser and having a look at the network traffic reveals that, in fact, several requests are being send asynchronously, with each but the last request being canceled by the next one.

In this case, the `open()` method is being invoked repeatedly on the same instance of an XMLHttpRequest inside the `sendRequest` method of `ajaxInstance`.